# What is the meaning of Lennon's actions with James in “Lovely, Dark and Deep?”

Tags: lovely-dark-and-deep

Near the end of the film [*Lovely, Dark and Deep*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovely,_Dark,_and_Deep_(film)) (2023), the ranger Lennon goes out to search for a missing man named James. When she finds him — apparently having been taken away by the mysterious entities — he asks her "Are you real?", to which she responds "no," after which she leaves him there, walks away, and as far as we see, does not report that she found him to the other rangers.

What is the meaning of this ending? Is Lennon convinced that she is, in fact, not real for some reason? Does she think that letting him believe that she is an illusion will help her somehow (say, if she lets the entities take him, they might return Annie Zhang or her sister)? Or something else?